# Referencing another class in an Enum class

Tags: java, enums

I've created an Enum class to manage various systems in my code, however, I need to access another class in order to complete some code.

I've tried referencing the code like so:

```
    public NewSkillsMain plugin = NewSkillsMain.this;
```

however this always returns the error:

No enclosing instance of the type NewSkillsMain is accessible in scope

Does anyone know how to reference other classes from an Enum class? Thanks!

Comment: `this` refers to the non-static instance of the current class. Since you're in a different class, you'd need to have an instance of `NewSkillsMain` in your enum. You could have static variable in `NewSkillsMain` and set it equal to `this` in the constructor so that could could access it like `NewSkillsMain.INSTANCE`, or wrap it in `NetSkillsMain.getInstance()` like a Singleton. Note that this is not the best approach.

Comment: @nrubin29 I put this in my Enum Class:

Comment: public static NewSkillsMain plugin = NewSkillsMain.getNewSkills();

Comment: And I also put this in my NewSkillsMain class:

Comment: public static NewSkillsMain getNewSkills(){
     return this;
    }

Comment: However I get an error, do you know if there is any static substitute for "this"?

Comment: I am assuming that you are using Bukkit and making a Minecraft plugin. Try this video I made that should show you how to use a singleton, which could work here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6LU1WK3JF4&list=PLAF3anQEEkzSmWCd_G-S-hMwaAXLp8xv0